# UITextField text disappears on every other keystroke

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, uitextview

Here is a video of the phenomena:
http://youtu.be/c0TP8YVF9TE

As the video shows, the value in exampleTextView.text is not lost. Its just hidden every other keystroke.

Solutions tried: 
I do not set the exampleTextView.text value to something during the program, except after the return key is pressed (and commenting that line out changes nothing).

I have set:

```
self.exampleTextView.clearsOnBeginEditing=NO;
self.exampleTextView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=NO;
self.exampleTextView.clearsOnInsertion=NO;
```

Edit:
Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/andrewschreiber/6970283

Comment: I think community people can help you if you show us your code.

Comment: @Andrew Schreiber, Please upload your project so people can find exact solution.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had almost the same problem. Sometimes the text was disappearing.

I solved it after changing the position of the UITextField in the view hierarchy in the xib file.

[image]

Comment: This is very strange. Just to clarify, this fixes the problem if you want to call `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewWillAppear`. The answers below work as well moving the call to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: What a shameful bug on Apple's part

Comment: This still solves the issue for Xcode 7.0.1 storyboards. Thanks!

Comment: This was not the case for me.  Mine was at the bottom of the list.  The other solution by user3339688 did work for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Moving textfields to be topmost ui element worked. Crazy.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same problem. My solution was to remove `[_textField becomeFirstResponder]` from the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method. This bug only occurs if the viewcontroller was presented modally.

Comment: Yes if you want to make that text field first responder than make it in         viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear. Your problem will solve.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the `UITextField`'s `becomeFirstResponder` from `viewWillAppear` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` fixed this for my case. I also made sure to add `resignFirstResponder` on the `UITextField` to the actions that were dismissing the view (which was presented modally).

Comment: I even had to place it in viewDidAppear. Otherwise it resulted in invisible text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use all the Delegate method of UITextField . and please let me know what are you trying to do with Done Button clicked , only set the text of anything else or if you share all the code with me then i can help you

Please  replace your textFieldShouldReturn method with my method and also implementing the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method in your code and its working fine

```
 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField {

          [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];


    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;


}
```

Comment: I tried this, both with 'return YES' and 'return NO' in textFieldShouldReturn. That did not solve the problem, but gave me some ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

On my storyboard, I switched the text from 'Plain' to 'Attributed' then back to 'Plain' again.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. The other solution from SbClx did.

Comment: Ok, changed correct answer as others seem to have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

@SbClx 's solution works for me, but I have another workaround that also works: set the background of the UITextField to any UIImage you like.

After some trial and error, I found that the bug disappears when I set the borderStyle of UITextField to UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, which is unfortunately not what I wanted, I want a simple white background.

The documentation of UITextField.borderStyle states that: If the value is set to the UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect style, the custom background image associated with the text field is ignored.
So I guess background image might have something to do with the bug too.