# UITextField - text is jumping and out of aligning while typing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm having problems with UITextFields across my app:

- in one case while typing, the text is not aligned, and when i finish editing it aligns back.
- on the other case, while typing, The text disappears and reappears with every key tap.

I checked on a real device and on the simulator as well, and it happens in both.

I have looked all over and found that post -
[Disappearing UITextField text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494543/disappearing-uitextfield-text) , but non of the solutions suggested here worked for me.

I checked and it happens both on iOS 8.x and iOS 9.x.

[image: As you can see the text is way down below]

**EDIT:**

- No UIAppearance
- No Custom fonts
- The Controller is a UITableViewController
- TextFields are in a UIView container in XIB file subviewed into the UITableView header

The UIView that holds the UITextField

```
    class IBAddNewMediaHeaderView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var StoryTitle:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SelectDate:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ClientProfilePic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addMediaButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    }
}
```

[image]

I understand that this is not a lot of info but i really don't know what to look for, anyway i tried to give you as much info as i can, if you need any more info that will help you figure this out just ask.

Comment: You're not giving us much to work on... Any code or storyboards? Do you use any baseline or first baseline constraints? Do you use UIAppearance? Custom fonts? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** 
Ok after i have tried anything possible to find out why this is happening i understood that the problem happens only if i put the .becomeFirstResponder for the UITextView in the viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear methods, so obviously the answer is to make the textField first responder in the view controller's presentation in the viewDidAppear.