# UITextField text disappearing while typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitextfield

Strange behaviour observed on UITextField text disappears,

**Steps**:
Type text in UITextField and click home button.
Open another application (App) and click home button.
Then Open First App the UITextField in text is disappears.
Issue observed in IPhone 6s version 9.2.1.  but perfectly working in simulator.

Comment: do you store typed text any where? that allocated to the textfiled?

Comment: Not able to reproduce in my case, Check if there is any code in viewwillappear which is making textbox empty or applicationdidenterforeground.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352663/uitextfield-text-disappears-on-every-other-keystroke

Comment: Not able to reproduce either. Maybe you can create a breakpoint and run your app in debug mode to retry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494543/disappearing-uitextfield-text Same issue which i am refering !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disappearing UITextField text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494543/disappearing-uitextfield-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can override this method in your custom responders to update your object's state or perform some action such as highlighting the selection. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

The custom Class should be similar to:

```
class CustomSecureTextField: UITextField { 
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        super.becomeFirstResponder()
         //if !isSecureTextEntry {
         //  return true 
         //} 
         if let currentText = text {  
             insertText(currentText)
         } 
         return true
    } 
}
```