# Focused UITextField loses align and starts flickering when back to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have UITextField that is a first responder, when appropriate button is pressed application goes to background and opens Phone app. When I get back to my app instead of centre vertical alignment it appears as bottom vertical alignment and it appears/disappears after every second letter is inputed. I tried several solutions, but non of them worked. If I pop the screen, and come back to it again problem is fixed, but after going to background and foreground again this bug appears again.

Comment: running into this same problem... wish there was a solution... :-/

Comment: Don't know if it's exactly the same issue but worked for me: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352663/uitextfield-text-disappears-on-every-other-keystroke/21092705#21092705)

Comment: I had the same problem and answer from this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352663/uitextfield-text-disappears-on-every-other-keystroke) resolve it. You need to change the position of the UITextField in the xib view hierarchy.