# UITextField - text is jumping and out of aligning when app comes from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a textField, the text in which jumps and goes out of aligning when I type in.

I did try following after going through many stack questions related to same issue,

When app goes to background,

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
textField.layoutIfNeeded()
```

And when app comes back to foreground,

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
textField.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Some people pointed out that `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` should be called in `viewDidAppear` method, but none of this seems to be working.

Comment: Your view controller lifecycle methods (example viewWillAppear etc) will not be called in the first place when you transition between background and foreground.

Comment: @ Happiehappie : I am aware of the fact that controller lifecycle methods will not be called during transition between active and inactive state. Many stack overflow questions suggested this solution for the text jumping issue, so I tried setting becomeFirstResponder() in viewDidAppear method.
thanks anyway..:)

Comment: Have you tried my method?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21092705/1343314)  solved my problem..  Thanks for your time.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller's lifecycle won't be called when when you transition between active and inactive state. This is a sudden solution I think of.

In applicationDidEnterBackground

```
self.window?.endEditing(true)
```

Then when you are becoming active again, check if your current shown vc is this vc with the text field, then only become first responder.